# Sharepoint file upload randomly results in access denied error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive, sharepoint-api

Since yesterday, the file upload api keeps returning 403 randomly. But it depends on the sharepoint. Many of our clients dont seem to encounter the issue, but our own sharepoint, and a new client's sharepoint have this problem.

Basically every upload request either succeeds or returns 403 Access denied error. And more often than not, it returns 403:

Here is an example of a request (client's sharepoint):

```
error: "{
↵  "error": {
↵    "code": "accessDenied",
↵    "message": "Access denied",
↵    "innerError": {
↵      "date": "2020-10-14T08:51:20",
↵      "request-id": "cacf89c3-5dbc-4390-98a1-5d7cb9e2668d",
↵      "client-request-id": "cacf89c3-5dbc-4390-98a1-5d7cb9e2668d"
↵    }
↵  }
↵}"
```

Another example (our sharepoint):

```
error: "{
↵  "error": {
↵    "code": "accessDenied",
↵    "message": "Access denied",
↵    "innerError": {
↵      "date": "2020-10-14T09:01:38",
↵      "request-id": "3c23f74d-579b-41e8-aafc-a6e3b3a6d885",
↵      "client-request-id": "3c23f74d-579b-41e8-aafc-a6e3b3a6d885"
↵    }
↵  }
↵}"
```

Nothing has been changed on our sharepoint, it used to always work, no code change, no configuration change on sharepoint.

**Edit**, code being used for upload:

```php
    private function uploadSmallFile(string $localFilePath, string $remoteFilePath, $conflictBehavior)
    {
        $route = "/sites/root/drive/items/root:$remoteFilePath:/content";

        $route = $route . '?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=' . $conflictBehavior;

        $item = $this->client->createRequest('PUT', $route, true)
            ->setReturnType(Model\DriveItem::class)
            ->attachBody(file_get_contents($localFilePath))
            ->execute();

        return $item;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the HTTP call which you are using?

Comment: Sure, added the code being used in the original post @Shiva-MSFTIdentity

Comment: Could you please try in Postman and let me know if its still the case? Just check with itemid as well.

Comment: Please also check whether you can access the onedrive using Browser(UI).

Comment: Also please specify the content type in the header.

Comment: Posted details below @Shiva-MSFTIdentity and now it seems to not happen anymore since around 11 am CEST....... very strange, no code was changed on my side, just kept testing. Is it fixed ?

Comment: Problem is back again....... now for all clients whose code didn't change since june...used to work fine before. Could you look into it @Shiva-MSFTIdentity ?

Answer (score 0):

Further details:

Accessing sharepoint on the browser works fine.

Using Insomnia (like Postman but for all uses), here is what happens with a path (Content-Type and Content-Length specified):

- Successful upload (201),  403 Access denied (although it happens twice in about 50 uploads in Insomnia)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "Access denied",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-10-15T07:34:19",
      "request-id": "cf7f0f59-046c-4115-ab67-3f471f340dca",
      "client-request-id": "cf7f0f59-046c-4115-ab67-3f471f340dca"
    }
  }
}
```

With itemId:

- Only Successful upload

This is strange, because I'm pretty sure it's not code related, since this happens on a codebase thats as old as june 2020 and didn't change since then.

**Edit**: Problem seems to be solved, no code was changed on my side. API Related problem.

**Edit 2**: Problem is back as of today 20-10-2020 (at least since 8am CEST)

Comment: Did the issue resolve itself for you?  I am facing similar issue, in my case i have an Azure function that uses Microsoft Graph API (via. Graph SDK) to upload files to SharePoint, the application has been working without this particular issue for almost a month, and suddenly today there are few random 403 (accessDenied) issue.

Comment: Did not really do anything on my end @user527614 it just disappeared

Comment: Thanks @Herz3h.  I too notice that the accessDenied issue is no longer occurring.  I guess the inbuilt retry mechanism of Graph SDK is not sufficient.